# Date in varchar format of two different types need to be changed to a date in varchar of a specific format

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a column LOGIN_DATETIME from LOGIN table

The column is varchar2 has values in two format

1. `20-11-2018 01:00:00`
2. `20-07-2018 14:00`

I need to derive a varchar value from this column with the following format

```
dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mi am/pm
```

Result expected

1. `20-Nov-2018 01:00 AM`
2. `20-Jul-2018 02:00 PM`

I tried like

Format 1:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LOGIN_DATETIME, 'DD-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss'), 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mi AM') 
FROM LOGIN
WHERE LOGIN_DATETIME is not null;
```

Format 2:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LOGIN_DATETIME, 'DD-mm-yyyy hh:mi'), 'dd-mmm-yyyy hh:mi AM') 
FROM LOGIN
WHERE LOGIN_DATETIME is not null;
```

It's not working.

Comment: Do you mean your column have all 2 values `'20-11-2018 01:00:00'` AND `'20-07-2018 14:00'`?

Comment: two kinds are there one type is dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss and dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi

Comment: Alter column data type to TIMESTAMP.

Comment: This is another good example an why it is an extremely bad idea to store DATE or TIMESTAMP values in a varchar column.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this only one query:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN LENGTH(login_datetime) = 19 THEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(login_datetime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MI AM')
        WHEN LENGTH(login_datetime) = 16 THEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(login_datetime, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH:MI AM')
    END AS login_datetime
FROM login
ORDER BY 1;
```

Tested ok in [rextester](https://rextester.com/NRVA43292)

Answer (score 0):

That was easy one I dunno the syntax of SQL it was mon not mmm in date format

```
SELECT
TO_char(to_timestamp (LOGIN_DATETIME, 'DD-MM-RRRR HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH12:mi AM')
from LOGIN
WHERE LOGIN_DATETIME is NOT null;
```

OR

```
 SELECT
TO_char(to_timestamp (LOGIN_DATETIME, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'DD-Mon-YYYY HH12:mi AM')
from LOGIN
WHERE LOGIN_DATETIME is NOT null;
```

The both formats work in one query itself.

Answer (score 0):

Use case and select format based on field length

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN LENGTH(LOGIN_DATETIME) = 16 THEN TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LOGIN_DATETIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi'), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mi AM')
  ELSE TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(LOGIN_DATETIME, 'dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss'), 'dd-mm-yyyy HH:mi AM') 
  END
FROM LOGIN
WHERE LOGIN_DATETIME is not null;
```